# pagestyle apply to first page of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, page-numbering

I have a problem centering the page number only on the FIRST page of Bibliography. Following is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} % "openright" starts each chapter on an odd-page, remove if not needed
\usepackage[top=2.54 cm, bottom=2.54 cm, left=2.54 cm, right=2.54 cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % put before apacite

% define two styles : prelim and main
\fancypagestyle{prelim}{
\fancyhf{} %clear all headers and footers fields
\cfoot{\thepage} %prints the page number on the center side of the footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{main}{
\fancyhf{} %clear all headers and footers fields
\chead{\thepage} %prints the page number on the center side of the header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{prelim}}

    \begin{document}
% apply prelim styles for table of contentsl

\pagestyle{prelim} % roman page number from this page
\pagenumbering{roman} % roman page number from this page
\thispagestyle{empty} % no roman page number on this page

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables % if necessary
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures % if necessary
\newpage

% apply main style for chapter and reference
\pagestyle{main} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
        \include{chp1}
        \newpage

        \bibliographystyle{apacite}
            \bibliography{mybib} % this is mybib 

    \end{document}
```

% chp1.txt is

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{main}
  Text for Introduction.
```

Comment: I can't compile your code as is, obviously. When I hacked it in order to make it usable, it worked fine. The page number is in the centre of the footer, just as you've defined.

Comment: Thanks. For table of contents, I want it to be in the center of the footer, but for other I want it to be on the center of the header. It works for all, but the first page of the Bibliography. I can't add Bibliography here so there was an error. But, even with that you can still see that page number is in the bottom for the first page, while I want it at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `\def\thispagestyle#1{}` solves the problem

```
\newpage
\def\thispagestyle#1{} % add this 
        \bibliographystyle{apacite}
            \bibliography{mybib} % this is mybib
```

Comment: And now `\thispagestyle` will no longer work for the rest of your document.

Comment: Thanks @cfr. It's fine for my problem. But, it may not be a good solution for other problems.

Comment: Just redefine the `plain` style again before the bibliography.

Comment: Please feel free to update the answer.